# mysql charset cli

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, command-line-interface

how do i determine what a mysql db's charset is set to? in the cli?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE db-name
```

Will show you the default character set for the database,

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE db-name.table-name
```

Will show you the character set for a specific table (along with a lot of other information).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command "show table status",

it will show you a lot of information (including character set) about your tables

mysql> show table status;

Comment: it shows the `collation` and other info, but not the `CHARSET`